# Click handler fired only once

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a set of links that I iterate over and add click handlers.  Each link when clicked, fires an ajax request which upon success creates a div containing response data, and appends it to the DOM.  The newly appended div (a floating div similar to a small lightbox) however, is removed when the user clicks close(on the div) or clicks anywhere else on the screen.  I have a simple script below to monitor this change, but the click handler fires only once and does not work until after a page refresh.  What am I doing incorrectly?

```
var monitorChange = function () {
    //Check if div has been appended to the dom and if so continue to monitor it
    if ( $('div.justappended').length > 0 ) 
    {
        setTimeout(monitorChange,100);
    } 
    else 
    {
        //div has been removed from the dom
        alert('div removed');
        //...do additional stuff here
    }
};

$( 'span.someElements' ).each( function () {
    var that = $(this);
    $(that).click( monitorChange );
});
```

Comment: Just so you know, in your last each loop, `that` is already a jQuery object, so you don't need `$(that)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I understand, you are looking to have your on click event still work with ajax generated code.  You need to use the live command in this case.  http://api.jquery.com/live/

$('span.someElements').live('click', monitorChange);